# How i can set Default value in CheckboxListTile in flutter based on Condition?

Tags: flutter, api

I have to set default selected value of CheckboxListTile so how i can set.

My api response as below.

```
{
  "responseCode": 200,
  "responseMessage": "Success",
  "data": null,
  "dataList": [
    {
      "createdate": "12-01-2022 07:25 PM",
      "updatedate": "12-01-2022 07:25 PM",
      "createdByName": "admin admin",
      "lastModifiedByName": "admin admin",
      "createdById": 1,
      "lastModifiedById": 1,
      "id": 5,
      "partnerid": 1,
      "paymentGateWayId": 3,
      "paymentGateWayName": "Bill desk",
      "defaultpgflag": "No",
      "isDeleted": false
    },
    {
      "createdate": "12-01-2022 07:26 PM",
      "updatedate": "24-01-2022 07:11 PM",
      "createdByName": "admin admin",
      "lastModifiedByName": "admin admin",
      "createdById": 1,
      "lastModifiedById": 1,
      "id": 6,
      "partnerid": 1,
      "paymentGateWayId": 2,
      "paymentGateWayName": "CCAvenue",
      "defaultpgflag": "No",
      "isDeleted": false
    },
    {
      "createdate": "24-01-2022 07:11 PM",
      "updatedate": "24-01-2022 07:11 PM",
      "createdByName": "admin admin",
      "lastModifiedByName": "admin admin",
      "createdById": 1,
      "lastModifiedById": 1,
      "id": 8,
      "partnerid": 1,
      "paymentGateWayId": 1,
      "paymentGateWayName": "Payu-Money",
      "defaultpgflag": "Yes",
      "isDeleted": false
    }
  ],
  "excelDataList": null,
  "totalRecords": 3,
  "pageRecords": 0,
  "currentPageNumber": 0,
  "totalPages": 0
}
```

I Bind all data to checkedbox as below.
[image]

So here i have to set default checked value which have **defaultpgflag == Yes**.

As API Response Payu-Money have defaultpgflag==Yes. so by default Payu-Money is default selected.

My CheckedBox Code as below.

```
...configByPartnerId.map(
              (item) => CheckboxListTile(
                title: Text(item.paymentGateWayName!),
                selected: checked.contains(item),
                value: checked.contains(item),
                onChanged: (bool? value) {
                  if (value!) {
                    setState(() {
                      setState(() {
                        if (checked.isEmpty == false) {
                          checked.removeAt(0);
                        }
                        print("remove at 0----------------------");
                      });
                      print("add item_______________________");
                      checked.add(item);
                      print(item.paymentGateWayName);
                    });
                  } else {
                    setState(() {
                      print("remove item______________________");
                      checked.remove(item);
                    });
                  }
                },
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: you have to populate `checked` array with "checked" items, now it is empty so it means that no items are checked by default

Comment: please can you explain in some more details.?

Comment: `checked` array contains "selected" items, now it is initialized to empty array - thats why no item is selected by default - if you add to `checked` array some items then those items will be marked as "selected"

Comment: okay, i got the data which i want and i set it to -- var checkedItem;  now how i can set the default value which is Payu-Money?

Comment: it stores values which i select the checkbox.